# C# image loses transparency when loaded in clipboard even with DIBv5 conversion

Tags: c#, clipboard, transparency, dib

I'm trying to load an image file into the clipboard in order to then paste it in Discord with Ctrl+V. It is possible to paste a PNG into Discord and conserve the transparency, as I am able to right click to copy an image on Mozilla or Chrome and then press Ctrl+V to paste it into the Discord client. A look to the clipboard content shows that Mozilla stores `DeviceIndependantBitmap` and `Format17` data formats after copying an image. I therefore adapted the functions from the post [Copying From and To Clipboard loses image transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177115/copying-from-and-to-clipboard-loses-image-transparency) to convert an `Image` object into `DIBv5` data and load it in the clipboard under the `DeviceIndependantFormat` name.

However the transparency is not supported. When then pasting the image into Discord, all transparent regions are filled with a black color.
Here is the script used to test the loading of a PNG in the clipboard. The DIB header is built to exactly match Mozilla's DIB header when an image is copied (with only width, height and number of pixels information changed):

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClipboardDIBTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Loads a PNG with transparency in the clipboard.
            SetClipboardImage(Image.FromFile("./test.png"));
        }

        /// <summary>Loads an image into the DIBv5 format in the clipboard,
        /// under the `DeviceIndependantBitmap` format.</summary>
        static void SetClipboardImage(Image image)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
            DataObject data = new DataObject();
            using (MemoryStream dibV5MemStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Byte[] dibV5Data = ConvertToDIBv5(image);
                dibV5MemStream.Write(dibV5Data, 0, dibV5Data.Length);
                data.SetData(DataFormats.Dib, false, dibV5MemStream);
                // The 'copy=true' argument means the MemoryStreams can be safely disposed after the operation.
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>Retrieves bitmap data from the image, ensuring an ARGB pixel format.</summary>
        static Byte[] GetBM32Data(Image image)
        {
            Byte[] bm32bData;
            // Ensure image is 32bppARGB by painting it on a new 32bppARGB image.
            using (Bitmap bm32b = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
            {
                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm32b))
                    gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, bm32b.Width, bm32b.Height));
                // Bitmap format has its lines reversed.
                bm32b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                bm32bData = GetImageData(bm32b);
            }

            return bm32bData;
        }

        /// <summar>Retrieves the pixel data from a bitmap.</summary>
        static byte[] GetImageData(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
            int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
            byte[] data = new byte[bytes];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, data, 0, bytes);
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            return data;
        }

        /// <summary>Converts the image into a DIBv5 (Format17) data format.</summary>
        static Byte[] ConvertToDIBv5(Image image)
        {
            Byte[] bm32bData = GetBM32Data(image);
            Int32 width = image.Width;
            Int32 height = image.Height;

            // Header data built to match Mozilla's Format17 content when an image is copied.

            Int32 hdrSize = 124;
            Byte[] fullImage = new Byte[hdrSize + bm32bData.Length];
            //Int32 bV5Size;
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 0, 4, true, (UInt32)hdrSize);
            //Int32 bV5Width;
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 4, 4, true, (UInt32)width);
            //Int32 bV5Height;
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 8, 4, true, (UInt32)height);
            //Int16 bV5Planes;
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 12, 2, true, 1);
            //Int16 bV5BitCount;
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 14, 2, true, 32);
            //Int32 bV5Compression;
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 16, 4, true, 0);
            //Int32 biSizeImage;
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 20, 4, true, (UInt32)bm32bData.Length);
            // These are all 0. Since .net clears new arrays, don't bother writing them.
            //Int32 bV5XPelsPerMeter = 0;
            //Int32 bV5YPelsPerMeter = 0;
            //Int32 bV5ClrUsed = 0;
            //Int32 bV5ClrImportant = 0;
            //Int32 Red/Green/Blue/Alpha masks
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 40, 4, true, 0x000000FF);
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 44, 4, true, 0x0000FF00);
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 48, 4, true, 0x00FF0000);
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 52, 4, true, 0xFF000000);
            // Int32 bV5CSType : "sRGB"
            WriteIntToByteArray(fullImage, 56, 4, true, 1934772034);
            // Rest is all 0

            Array.Copy(bm32bData, 0, fullImage, hdrSize, bm32bData.Length);
            return fullImage;
        }

        static void WriteIntToByteArray(Byte[] data, Int32 startIndex, Int32 bytes, Boolean littleEndian, UInt32 value)
        {
            Int32 lastByte = bytes - 1;
            if (data.Length < startIndex + bytes)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", "Data array is too small to write a " + bytes + "-byte value at offset " + startIndex + ".");
            for (Int32 index = 0; index < bytes; index++)
            {
                Int32 offs = startIndex + (littleEndian ? index : lastByte - index);
                data[offs] = (Byte)(value >> (8 * index) & 0xFF);
            }
        }

        static UInt32 ReadIntFromByteArray(Byte[] data, Int32 startIndex, Int32 bytes, Boolean littleEndian)
        {
            Int32 lastByte = bytes - 1;
            if (data.Length < startIndex + bytes)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", "Data array is too small to read a " + bytes + "-byte value at offset " + startIndex + ".");
            UInt32 value = 0;
            for (Int32 index = 0; index < bytes; index++)
            {
                Int32 offs = startIndex + (littleEndian ? index : lastByte - index);
                value += (UInt32)(data[offs] << (8 * index));
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

- The original image file:

[image: Original PNG image, with transparency.]

- The pasted image in Discord with Ctrl+V, after running the program:

[image: Pasted result in Discord. Transparent regions are filled with black.]

I tried the following during my debugging/retroengineering attempts:

- Copying an image from Mozilla (with right click and copy), then reading the data stored in the clipboard under the `Format17` name, and saving it into a file before loading the content of the file into the clipboard again. If loaded under the `Format17` name nothing happens on Ctrl+V (Discord doesn't detect anything to paste). But if loaded under `DeviceIndependantBitmap` then the image is correctly pasted in Discord (with transparency).
- Making use of the same code from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177115/copying-from-and-to-clipboard-loses-image-transparency) mentioned above to load the picture in the simpler DIB format, though it gives a black background as well.

Other posts I've read:

- [How can I convert a CF_DIBV5 from Clipboard (Format17) to a Transparent Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333336/how-can-i-convert-a-cf-dibv5-from-clipboard-format17-to-a-transparent-bitmap)
- [How to paste a transparent image from the clipboard in a C# winforms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273669/how-to-paste-a-transparent-image-from-the-clipboard-in-a-c-sharp-winforms-app)
- [How can I put a device-independent bitmap into the Windows clipboard using just direct WinAPI? (No MFC or other wrappers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903416/how-can-i-put-a-device-independent-bitmap-into-the-windows-clipboard-using-just)
- [Win32 clipboard and alpha channel images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689541/win32-clipboard-and-alpha-channel-images)

Does anyone have an idea on why this happens and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: [Copying From and To Clipboard loses image transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46424800/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi It's exactly the post I mentioned in my question, which doesn't work for me as I explained.

Comment: @Krafpy A binary compare of the output of my own code to make the DIBs and the output from Chrome putting it on the clipboard shows some differences... might be worth doing a compare and seeing exactly what's different.

Comment: @Nyerguds As I explained in my question, I adapted your version to DIBv5, and made so the header of the DIB stored by Mozilla and my version are exactly the same.

Comment: I'm not sure Chrome actually reads DIB5. My tests seemed to indicate that it only looks at the normal DIB. Though strangely enough, making and restoring a complete dump of everything in the clipboard as accurately as possible still removed transparency when pasting in Chrome, so I'm wondering if there is either something else in the clipboard that we can't access through the .net code, or if there is something in the default "Bitmap" format that can affect that. I'm not sure if there's a way to get/set the actual binary data of that format; old docs seem to suggest it's a bare pointer.

Comment: @Nyerguds I think there may be something weird going on with the C# Bitmap class or clipboard, as it also adds artifacts on images (weird outlines around corners). But as I explained it in my post, dumping the clipboard data from Mozilla to a file and then loading it back to the clipboard works and keeps the transparency when pasted in Discord. Another thing I noticed : when manually creating bitmap pixel data, having pixel values of either 0x000000 or 0xFFXXXXXX works. But if a single one pixel has a transparency value that isn't 0 or 255, then all transparent pixels turn black.

Comment: Some of these posts talk about it working if the DIB uses "premultiplied" alpha. I honestly never looked into how that's done, but that might be the solution?